# No Tag Wiki tab in Tags Section

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

For people who, like me, want to edit the tag-wikis and add/modify information in them and are willing to do the research, it's difficult to find tags that have wiki information on them already - you have to sort through *all* of the tags to do this.  I propose a tab in the 'tags' section for 'stubs' (for want of a better phrase) for people to identify tags that have no wiki and go off and do the research.  Rather like the 'unanswered' section in the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding tags without Wikis can already be easily done via Stack Exchange Data Explorer. For example:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/87345/most-popular-tags-without-wikis

Comment: I was too lazy to site-switch from SO to SFF for the links, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was unaware of that.